# Suggestion/Recommendation engine for processes

Tags: java, algorithm, oracle, autosuggest, recommendation-engine

I have some tables with several jobs, dependencies and elapsed times. The purpose of the engine is that when you insert the name of the job, it gives you a recommendation about what process to check in order to make it faster.

For example, given the next table:

```
    jobs
    +----+-------------------------+------------+-----+
    | id | job_name                | parent_job |type |
    +----+-------------------------+------------+-----+
    | 1  | delete_everything_box   |            |b    |
    | 2  | delete_everything       | 2          |j    |
    | 3  | another_job             |            |j    |
    | 4  | dependant_box           |            |b    |
    | 5  | dependant_job_1         | 4          |j    |
    | 6  | dependant_job_2         | 4          |j    |
    +----+-------------------------+------------+-----+
```

Job dependant_box may have a dependency -even several-, described in another table:

```
    dependencies
    +--------+-------------------------+------+
    | job_id | condition_job           | type |
    +--------+-------------------------+------+
    | 4      | delete_everything_box   | b    |
    +--------+-------------------------+------+
```

Then, you have a table where every single elapsed time is stored (A):

```
    timings
    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
    | job_id | start_time           | end_time            | status   | elapsed_time    |
    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
    | 1      | 2012/09/19 02:57:35  | 2012/09/20 02:59:38 | success  | 86523           |
    | 2      | 2012/09/19 02:57:36  | 2012/09/20 02:59:37 | success  | 86521           |
    | 3      | 2012/09/19 02:57:36  | 2012/09/19 02:59:37 | success  | 121             |
    | 4      | 2012/09/20 02:59:39  | 2012/09/20 03:05:02 | success  | 323             |
    | 5      | 2012/09/20 02:59:40  | 2012/09/20 03:01:01 | success  | 81              |
    | 6      | 2012/09/20 02:59:40  | 2012/09/20 03:05:01 | success  | 321             |
    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

So, let's say that you enter a job name, in this case "delete_everything_box". From A, you can deduce that *delete_everything* is the culprit. But there is another scenario (B):

```
timings

    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
    | job_id | start_time           | end_time            | status   | elapsed_time    |
    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
    | 1      | 2012/09/19 02:57:35  | 2012/09/20 02:59:38 | success  | 86523           |
    | 2      | 2012/09/19 02:57:36  | 2012/09/20 02:59:37 | success  | 86521           |
    | 3      | 2012/09/19 02:57:36  | 2012/09/19 02:59:37 | success  | 121             |
    | 4      | 2012/09/19 02:57:35  | 2012/09/20 03:05:02 | success  | 86847           |
    | 5      | 2012/09/20 02:59:39  | 2012/09/20 03:01:01 | success  | 82              |
    | 6      | 2012/09/20 02:59:39  | 2012/09/20 03:05:01 | success  | 322             |
    +--------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

In B if you enter the name dependant_box, it is going to tell you that *delete_everything* is the culprit. This is because since it has dependencies, it will wait until all the dependencies are satisfied to start running. It can also happen that several jobs are chained so you have to check all of them, or at least the 5 with higher elapsed time.

So, having the given information it should show 10 candidates to optimize, which are going to be entered into the engine. It can also happen that some of the jobs couldn't be fixed, so they shouldn't be shown. Also, there could be that some jobs take longer or are chained, but the weightage is based on elapsed time.

The tables are stored in oracle, and the language should be java.

What do you suggest? We are talking about developing an automatized tool for a team to check jobs that are taking longer. If you can point me to algorithms, libraries and so on, it will be appreciated.

I forgot to mention it: **b** means box which contains 1 or many jobs (j). **j** is a single job entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great open source tools available for Java with the features you mention; check out these two:

1. [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner)
2. [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features)